# QGIS treatment modeler to python script

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler, qgis-2.18, ppygis

I'm trying to make a little tool who do a concave hull, and calculate its surface in a new field.
I'm not a python pro, so I began with treatment modeler like this : [image]

It works very well !
But I have to treat more than hundred shapes, so I decide to save my model in python script and edit it to treat all shapes in a folder.
In first time, I wanted to try python script I saved. But strangely, it doesn't work... I have a weird message...
[image]

Here is my code :

```
##Calcule de surface cultivee=name
##couchedepiedsdevigne=vector
##couchedesortie=output vector

outputs_QGISCONCAVEHULL_1=processing.runalg('qgis:concavehull', couchedepiedsdevigne,0.3,False,False,None)
outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_1=processing.runalg('qgis:advancedpythonfieldcalculator', outputs_QGISCONCAVEHULL_1['OUTPUT'],"SURFACE",1,10.0,3.0,True,'$area',couchedesortie)
```

I don't understand why it's working in treatment modeler and not in python script...
Somebody can help me ?

Comment: which exact version of 2.18? Did you install from Development or Latest Release? Looks similar to [this issue](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16858)

Comment: I have QGIS 2.18.9

Answer (score 1):

You may be missing some dependecy imports and if you do not want to batch select hundreds of files you may use os.walk() to iterate through directory of many directories:

```
import processing, os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:/someRoot/shp/dir'):
  for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.shp'):
      shpFile = root + '//' + file
      outputs_QGISCONCAVEHULL_1 = processing.runalg('qgis:concavehull', shpFile,0.3,False,False,None)
      outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_1 = processing.runalg('qgis:advancedpythonfieldcalculator', outputs_QGISCONCAVEHULL_1['OUTPUT'],"SURFACE",1,10.0,3.0,True,'$area',couchedesortie)
```